# Add icon to datagrid . I want to add a video icon

Tags: angular, angular-material

[I want this instead of view and edit i need a video icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L7ww.png)

This is my view i add delete icon here. I also want to add a video icon

TypeScript:

```js
listArray: any = [];
  displayedColumns: any = [{
    'fieldName': "subject_name",
    'tableTitle': "Subject"
  }, {
    'fieldName': "meet_name",
    'tableTitle': "Meeting name"
  }, {
    'fieldName': "start",
    'tableTitle': "Meeting Time"
  },
  {
    'fieldName': "meet_code",
    'tableTitle': "Meeting Code"
  }];
   icon = "src/assets/icons/leader.png"
  extraColumns: any = ['Delete','Video']
  // extraColumns: any = ['DeleteQp']
  expansionPanelHeader: string = "meet_name";
  expansionPanelFields: any = [{
    'fieldName': "subject_name",
    'tableTitle': "Subject"
  }, {
    'fieldName': "start",
    'tableTitle': "Meeting Time"
  },
  {
    'fieldName': "meet_code",
    'tableTitle': "Meeting Code"
  }];
```

HTML:

```html
 <div class="content" *ngIf="listArray?.length > 0">
  <app-responsive-datagrid 
       [reload]="reload" [morePage]="morePage"
       [expansionPanelHeader]="expansionPanelHeader" 
       [expansionPanelFields]="expansionPanelFields"
       [dataSource]="listArray" [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns" 
      [extraColumns]="extraColumns"
     (loadMoreEvent)="receiveLoadMoreEvent($event)" 
      (rowOperation)="recieveRowOperation($event)">
  </app-responsive-datagrid>
</div>
```

[this is i getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyKel.png)  
How can I add video icon to the action column i tried video icon but it not reflecting. Can you help me to find a way to solve my problem?

Comment: Is the link to the image your expected result?

Comment: @gerstams No sir . I want a video  icon

Comment: Can you please attach an image or something that displays what you currently see so that we can move forward from there?

Comment: @gerstams i added an image what i need